# Unable to Give Dynamic Values to Jquery Select2 with HTML from a DropDown List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am developing a car project of my client as Gari.PK. He wants me to change the drop-downs and I am stuck on a problem. Here is my HTML code of a drop-down.

```
<select class="round-10 js-example-basic-single" name="c_version" id="c_version">
  <option value="">- Any Version -</option>
  <option value="XLi VVTi">XLi VVTi  <br><span style="color: red;">2016 . Petrol . Manual</span></option>
  <option value="GLi 1.3 VVTi">GLi 1.3 VVTi  <br><span style="color: red;">2016 . Petrol . Manual</span></option>
  <option value="GLi Automatic 1.3 VVTi">GLi Automatic 1.3 VVTi  <br><span style="color: red;">2016 . Petrol . Automatic</span></option>
  <option value="Altis Automatic 1.6">Altis Automatic 1.6  <br><span style="color: red;">2016 . Petrol . Automatic</span></option>
  <option value="Altis 1.8">Altis 1.8  <br><span style="color: red;">2016 . Petrol . Manual</span></option>
  <option value="Altis CVT i 1.8">Altis CVT i 1.8  <br><span style="color: red;">2016 . Petrol . Automatic</span></option>
  <option value="Altis Grande 1.8">Altis Grande 1.8  <br><span style="color: red;">2016 . Petrol . Manual</span></option>
  <option value="Altis Grande CVT i 1.8">Altis Grande CVT i 1.8  <br><span style="color: red;">2016 . Petrol . Automatic</span></option>
  <option value="">Other</option>
</select>
```

It appears like this on the front

[DropDown list mine and desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mOtN.png)

or see the http://www.gari.pk/used-cars/sell/ on the website.

I want to change my drop-down to a more attractive way as I am showing it in the bottom of the image.

But I am failed to do so. I am trying to use jQuery select2 but the problem is the Select2 is not picking the HTML from the 'option' tag. I have seen some posts saying that you can give data dynamically to Select2 us under:

```
var data = [
      { id: 0, text: '<div style="color:green">enhancement</div>' },
      { id: 1, text: '<div style="color:red">bug</div><div><small>This is some small text on a new line</small></div>' }];

  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
      data: data,
      templateResult: function (d) { return $(d.text); },
      templateSelection: function (d) { return $(d.text); },

  });
```

Now how can I pass the data from the 'option' tag to this above code.

Comment: you can use the chosen plugin and you have to create the `<optgroup>`.
link : https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: explain a bit more.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mOtN.png : the textbox is for what ? filtering?

Comment: It is a dropdown list with Jquery select2

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `templateResult` of `select2` and write your custom `templateResult` where you return **parsedHtml**. Also you need to use `escapeMarkup` option as well. Consider below example and working snippet:

```js
var data = [{
  id: "XLi VVTi",
  text: 'XLi VVTi  <br><span style="color: red;">2016 . Petrol . Manual</span>'
}, {
  id: "GLi 1.3 VVTi",
  text: 'GLi 1.3 VVTi  <br><span style="color: red;">2016 . Petrol . Manual</span>'
}, {
  id: "GLi Automatic 1.3 VVTi",
  text: 'GLi Automatic 1.3 VVTi  <br><span style="color: red;">2016 . Petrol . Automatic</span>'
}, {
  id: "Altis Automatic 1.6",
  text: 'Altis Automatic 1.6  <br><span style="color: red;">2016 . Petrol . Automatic</span>'
}, {
  id: "Altis 1.8",
  text: 'Altis 1.8  <br><span style="color: red;">2016 . Petrol . Manual</span>'
}, {
  id: "Altis CVT i 1.8",
  text: 'Altis CVT i 1.8  <br><span style="color: red;">2016 . Petrol . Automatic</span>'
}, {
  id: "Altis Grande 1.8",
  text: 'Altis Grande 1.8  <br><span style="color: red;">2016 . Petrol . Manual</span>'
}, {
  id: "Altis Grande CVT i 1.8",
  text: 'Altis Grande CVT i 1.8  <br><span style="color: red;">2016 . Petrol . Automatic</span>'
}, {
  id: "",
  text: 'Others'
}];


$(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
  data: data,
  escapeMarkup: function(m) {
    return m;
  },
  templateResult: function(d) {
    return $.parseHTML(d.text); //return parsed html since your text itself contains html elements
    //you can also move this code into a separate function and provide the function name for templateResult
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<select class="round-10 js-example-basic-single" name="c_version" id="c_version">

</select>
```

Now for `templateSelection` to work, you need to make a proper format so that you display your data properly after selected. Hope you will find a way for that.

Comment: please tell me how I can put the 'options' data in the var data:[{
  text: '<div style="color:green">enhancement</div>'
}] dynamically from the select

Comment: Remove it from `html` and keep it in `data` variable in your `js` file

Comment: how? can you give me an example please.

Comment: but can I give these value with Jquery or javascript

Comment: Yes, you can. That's what you have in above example.. Are these options loaded from DB?

Comment: Then you need to somehow do some `ajax` call to get the options and then load it to select2 plugin as `data`. Right now its hard-coded in javascript. Implement `ajax` call there..